# jquery form sometime did normal html post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

javascript:

```
 (function(){
        $('form').ajaxForm({
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('.bar').width('0%');
                $('#output').empty();
            },
            uploadProgress:function(event, position, total, percentComplete){
                $('.progress').show();
                $('.bar').width('0%');
            },
            complete:function(xhr){
                $('.progress').hide();
                $('.bar').width("100%");
                $('#output').html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }); 
    })();


    $("#upload").change(function(){
            $("form").submit();
        });
```

html:

```
<form method="POST" action="upload_ajax.php" name="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input id="upload" name="image" type="file">
    </form>
```

I have an input-file use **jquery.form.js** post to php and output the message on div if php detect any problem with upload file.

I test few time, it works fine but sometime if i try to click & select image very fast. it become normal post. I place this from inside of a pop-box and using jquery to `load()` another page. therefor I will need to make sure the form will not run the normal html post.

is any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't replicated the issue but you could try preventing the default action for the input being triggered by including `preventDefault` either just on the `change` event and also on the `keyup` event.

```
$("#upload").change(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("form").submit();
})
.keyup(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: it did not work, i just try, it still happen sometimes

Comment: Does it still happen if there is no `action` attribute on the form?

Comment: i just did few testing, i notice the problem is cause by load(); when i close the popBox div & click upload button, popBox div load the content again and it cause the script problem, I have change the div to iframe & it works perfect now, thx for help appreciate!